# Processing child Control Events in Windows Forms Components in C++

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-c++, custom-component

I am a noob to Windows Forms so this is likely a remedial question.  I have a child component with a button and a text field.  I want to use multiple instances of these in a parent component or form.  At runtime, when the user clicks one of the buttons, I want the parent to get the event to decide what to do with the associated text.

Coming from the long lost world of Borland C++ Builder, during design time, I would simply double-click on the buttons and handlers in the parent would be created which I could just elaborate the code.  With Windows Forms, the component controls are not clickable (at design time) from the parent and are "frozen".  It is not obvious to me how to pass any child button clicks to a parent.  I've tried things like changing the button modifier from private to public but that doesn't help.  How is this best accomplished.

Note I am using C++ as I am sharing header file definitions with an associated C++ embedded app.

-Bob

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

My apologies, I thought I was still in my C# search :(

---

This is slightly complicated if you actually want to bubble up an event, or very easy if you use methods.

**Methods:**

In your child container, add a constructor or property that takes in and stores the parent. Then in the button handler, call `this.Parent.ButtonClicked(this);` and of course in the parent, add a `ButtonClicked(ChildType child)` method. That should get you there that way.

**Custom Event:**

To use events, you need to add a few things. Firstly, add a custom `EventArgs` class as such:

```
class ChildClickedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    // include a ctor and property to store and retrieve the child instance.
}
```

Then add a public delegate for it:

```
public delegate void ChildClickedEventHandler(object sender, ChildClickedEventArgs e);
```

Then to your child class, add a ButtonClicked event:

```
public event ChildClickedEventHandler ChildClicked;
```

And finally, a helper method to raise it:

```
private OnButtonClicked()
{
    if (this.ChildClicked != null)
    {
        this.ChildClicked(this, new ChildClickedEventArgs(this));
    }
}
```

Then when you add the child class to the parent, add an event handler for each, and you can handle your custom event for your custom control.

**Alternatively:**

If you can expose the Button in your child class, simply do the above but register it to `this.child.Button.Clicked`, saving adding the event handler yourself.

Comment: Thanks...I will give these options a go!